# Single sign on multiple django project

Tags: django-orm

In our business case there are three projects as follows:

- ProjectA
- ProjectB
- ProjectC

**ProjectA** will contains the user registration, So if a user registed with ProjectA then he can access the projects(**ProjectB, ProjectC**, etc.) except the admin login. Each project having different admin site login.

In this scenario we used django multiple database concept with routers:-
http://dustinfarris.com/2012/2/sharing-django-users-and-sessions-across-projects/

After that the user and session will be routed to corresponding projects(I can able to get ProjectA users in other projects and also create a record with that user.)

**The problem is** while accessing the admin it use default(local database based on the router). But while updating the record it throws the following exception:

```
User matching query does not exist
```

(It checks the ProjectA user in local database)

My question is is there any possibility to specify the database(in router) for a particular action in admin? (When i login, display the list,etc. the admin needs to be use default db and while update the records related to ProjectA user means its need to be access the router db) Please anyone advise on this, thanks.